# PDF download from S3 behaving differently on chrome and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, pdf, internet-explorer-8, amazon-s3

I was trying to download PDF files from AWS S3 by setting content-disposition property.
But the name of the PDF being downloaded is different in Chrome and IE8.

```
def set_attachment_content_disposition file_name
      style= :original
      path = self.asset.path(style) 
      bucket_name = self.asset.bucket_name 
      obj = AWS::S3::S3Object.find(path, bucket_name) 
      obj.content_disposition = 'attachment; filename="' + file_name + '"' 
      obj.store 
end

def download file_name
...
... 
// getting the s3 resource model object
res.set_attachment_content_disposition("TEST")
redirect_to res.asset_expiring_url
end
```

Here in chrome the pdf is being automatically downloaded as "TEST.pdf" but in IE8 it is coming without extension.

And if I pass "TEST.pdf" instead of test to filename, the in chrome its get downloaded as TEST.pdf.pdf and in IE8, it gets downloaded as TEST.pdf

What I want is to be able to download files with a single pdf extension on both browsers.
Is there any property which I am missing?
This is the sample final url which I am getting on redirection:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_test_bucket/attachments/151/original/TEST-384239990.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=my_access_id&Expires=1384240783&Signature=my_signature

Comment: Just for kicks, what were the HTTP headers on the response?